# Smtp Configuration

Tags: magento2

Please explain briefy.

https://prnt.sc/ph9ed0 - if i give my gmail account details am getting the same error.

what should i have fill the above things in smtp.

i am getting this error:

5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p11sm4350116pgb.1 - gsmtp

Comment: @Priiya i have recently gmail configuration and working fine my side check in log file

Comment: @Priya have you enabled less secure app setting in your gmail account??

Comment: No. i didn't enable.

Comment: please enable it , after try the same.